# How to make a shadow effect in canvas element on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas

I would like to make a shadow effect in canvas element on hover, when I mouseover in element display shadow for specific element else remove shadow in canvas html5

Note:

1. canvas having multiple elements
2. on hover element show border shadow in this element but not in other
3. on placing image in canvas element or hovering other element remove from first

Here is what I've tried:

```
   <canvas id="collage" width="850" height="560"></canvas>
    var canvas = document.getElementById("collage");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var canvasLeft = canvas.offsetLeft;
    var canvasTop = canvas.offsetTop;
    canvas.ondrop = drop;
    canvas.ondragover = allowDrop;

    $(document).ready(function(e) {

    $("#listImage img").live('mouseover',function(){
        imgid = this.id;
        img = document.getElementById(imgid);
        img.onmousedown = mousedown;
        img.ondragstart = dragstart;
    });

    design=1;
    canvasLayout(canvasDesign10);

    $("#maxphotos").live('change',function(){
        $('#designList').html('Loading...')
        $.ajax(
        {
            url : "walldecor3/getdesign",
            type: "POST",
            data : 'designid='+$(this).val(),
            success:function(data)
            {
                if (data !=0)
                {
                    $('#designList').html(data)
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Sorry..! unable process your request");
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert('Error : ' + jqXHR.status);
            }
        });
        return false;

    });


    $("#designList img").live('click',function(){
        imgid = this.id;
        if(imgid =="design10")
        {
            design =canvasDesign10;
        }
        else if(imgid =="design20")
        {
            design =canvasDesign20;
        }
        else if(imgid =="design21")
        {
            design =canvasDesign21;
        }
        else if(imgid =="design30")
        {
            design =canvasDesign30;
        }
        else if(imgid =="design31")
        {
            design =canvasDesign31;
        }
        else if(imgid =="design32")
        {
            design =canvasDesign32;
        }
        else if(imgid =="design33")
        {
            design =canvasDesign33;
        }
        else if(imgid =="design40")
        {
            design =canvasDesign40;
        }
        else if(imgid =="design41")
        {
            design =canvasDesign41;
        }
        else if(imgid =="design42")
        {
            design =canvasDesign42;
        }
        else if(imgid =="design43")
        {
            design =canvasDesign43;
        }
        else if(imgid =="design50")
        {
            design =canvasDesign50;
        }
        else
        {
            design =canvasDesign1;
        }
        cleareCanvas()
        canvasLayout(design);
    });


    $("#cmbProduct").live('change',function(){

        var clgproduct =$(this).val();
        var clgorientation =$("#cmbOrientation").val();
        var clgformat =$("#cmbFormat").val();

        $.ajax(
        {
            url : "walldecor3/getCollagePrice",
            type: "POST",
                data:    'clgproduct='+  clgproduct+'&clgorientation=       '+clgorientation+ '&clgformat='+clgformat,
            success:function(prdata)
            {
                $('#clgprice').html(prdata)
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert('Error : ' + jqXHR.status);
            }
        });
        return false;

    });

    $("#cmbOrientation").live('change',function(){
        var clgorientation =$(this).val();
        $.ajax(
        {
            url : "walldecor3/getOrientation",
            type: "POST",
            data : 'clgorientation='+clgorientation,
            success:function(fdata)
            {

                if (fdata !="")
                {
                    $('#cformat').html(fdata)
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Sorry..! unable process your request");
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert('Error : ' + jqXHR.status);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
    $("#cmbFormat").live('change',function(){

        var clgproduct =$("#cmbProduct").val();
        var clgorientation =$("#cmbOrientation").val();
        var clgformat =$(this).val();

        $.ajax(
        {
            url : "walldecor3/getCollagePrice",
            type: "POST",
            data : 'clgproduct='+clgproduct+'&clgorientation='+clgorientation+'&clgformat='+clgformat,
            success:function(fdata)
            {
                $('#clgprice').html(fdata)
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert('Error : ' + jqXHR.status);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });




    function collides(rects, x, y) 
    {
    var isCollision = false;
    for (var i = 0, len = rects.length; i < len; i++) 
    {
        var left = rects[i].x, right = rects[i].x+rects[i].w;
        var top = rects[i].y, bottom = rects[i].y+rects[i].h;
        if (right >= x && left <= x && bottom >= y && top <= y) 
        {
            isCollision = rects[i];
        }
    }
    return isCollision;
    }
    //-change canvas layout--
    function canvasLayout(canvasDesign) 
    {

    // check if context exist
    if (canvas && canvas.getContext) 
    {
        // list of rectangles to render
        rects = canvasDesign;
        //alert(JSON.stringify(rects));
        // get context
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        if (context) 
        {
          for (var i = 0, len = rects.length; i < len; i++) 
          {
            context.strokeStyle = rects[i].c;  
            context.strokeRect(rects[i].x, rects[i].y, rects[i].w, rects[i].h);
          }

        }

        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(a) {

            console.log('mousemove: ' + a.offsetX + '/' + a.offsetY);

            var rect = collides(rects, a.offsetX, a.offsetY);
            if (a.offsetY > rect.y && a.offsetY < rect.y + rect.h &&      a.offsetX > rect.x && a.offsetX < rect.x + rect.w) 
            {
                //alert(rect.x+","+rect.y+","+rect.w+","+rect.h);
                context.strokeStyle = "#05EFFF";
                context.strokeRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.w, rect.h);
            }
            else
            {
                context.strokeStyle = "#CCCCCC";
                context.strokeRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.w, rect.h);
            }

        }, false);

        canvas.addEventListener('click', function(e) 
        {
            console.log('click: ' + e.offsetX + '/' + e.offsetY);
            var rect = collides(rects, e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
            if (rect) 
            {
                if(e.offsetX > (canvas.width/2))
                {
                    $('#editer').css('left','');
                    $('#editer').css('right','-10%');
                    $('#editer').css('display','inline-block');
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#editer').css('right','')
                    $('#editer').css('left','-10%');
                    $('#editer').css('display','inline-block');
                }
                //alert(canvas.width)
            } 
            else 
            {
                //alert('no collision');
            }
        }, false);

    }
    }

    var startOffsetX, startOffsetY;

    function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function mousedown(ev) {
    startOffsetX = ev.offsetX;
    startOffsetY = ev.offsetY;
    }

    function dragstart(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
    }

    function drop(ev) {

    ev.preventDefault();

    //var dropX = ev.clientX - canvasLeft - startOffsetX;
    //var dropY = ev.clientY - canvasTop - startOffsetY;

    var dropX = ev.offsetX - canvasLeft - startOffsetX;
    var dropY = ev.offsetY - canvasTop - startOffsetY;

    var id = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    var dropElement = document.getElementById(id);
    // draw the drag image at the drop coordinates

    if(design !=1)
    {
        var rect = collides(design, dropX, dropY);
    }
    else
    {
        var rect = collides(canvasDesign10, dropX, dropY);
    }


    if(dropElement != null)
    {
        if (dropY > rect.y && dropY < rect.y + rect.h && dropX > rect.x &&  dropX < rect.x + rect.w)
        {
            ctx.clearRect(rect.x, rect.y,rect.w,rect.h);
            ctx.drawImage(dropElement, rect.x, rect.y,rect.w,rect.h);
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
        return false;
    }
    function cleareCanvas()
    {           
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }

  [enter image description here][1]

i want like image arrow->
```

Comment: Short and Specific title please !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Here's one way:**

- Make an `isHovering` flag for each image.
- Listen for mousemove events,
- In the mousemove handler, hit-test each image. If the mouse is over an image then set it's flag indicating it's being hovered over. Otherwise clear the image's flag.
- Clear the canvas and redraw all images. Add shadows for any images being hovered over.

[image]

**Example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
function reOffset(){
  var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  offsetX=BB.left;
  offsetY=BB.top;        
}
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }
window.onresize=function(e){ reOffset(); }

var isDown=false;
var startX,startY;

ctx.shadowBlur=5;
ctx.fillStyle='skyblue';

var images=[{x:25,y:25,isHovering:false},{x:100,y:25,isHovering:false},{x:175,y:25,isHovering:false}];
draw();
$("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});

function draw(){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  for(var i=0;i<images.length;i++){
    var img=images[i];
    ctx.shadowColor=img.isHovering?'rgba(0,0,0,1)':'rgba(0,0,0,0)';
    ctx.fillRect(img.x,img.y,35,25);
  }
}


function handleMouseMove(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  mx=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  my=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  for(var i=0;i<images.length;i++){
    var img=images[i];
    var x=img.x;
    var y=img.y;
    img.isHovering=(mx>x && mx<x+35 && my>y && my<y+25);
  }
  draw();

}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Hover over shapes</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=100></canvas>
```

Comment: thank you! this answer is really very helpful for me.